# Lucene 4.6 IndexReader deletion

Tags: lucene

In the newest version of lucene, 4.6, the `IndexReader.deleteDocuments()` no longer exists. Someone told me I should use the `IndexWriter` instead. However, the API document shows that:

```
void deleteDocuments(Query... queries)
```

deletes the document(s) matching any of the provided queries,

```
void deleteDocuments(Query query)
```

deletes the document(s) matching the provided query,

```
void deleteDocuments(Term... terms)
```

deletes the document(s) containing any of the terms, and

```
void deleteDocuments(Term term)
```

deletes the document(s) containing term.

There is no method for deleting the docs by document ID.

Comment: Rewrite your code so you're working with your own domain keys (database primary key, etc) instead of the internal Lucene document ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Lucene doc IDs are ephemeral in `IndexWriter`, and can change at any moment (once a merge completes).

However, `IndexWriter` does have a `tryDeleteDocument()`, which takes a near-real-time `IndexReader` and an `int docID`.  If possible (no merges have completed since that `IndexReader` was opened), the delete will "work" and the method returns `true`.  If the method returns `false`, you must delete via `Term` or `Query`, or, re-open a new NRT reader and try the delete again.

Comment: And all the tutorials about lucene in the internet is version 3.0 or below , its quite annoying. The APIs are totally different.